# GLMM and BLUPs: high correlation between random effects in a logistic GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic, singular-matrix

**Background:**

In an experiment, subjects had to choose whether they wanted an immediate reward or to wait for a larger reward (dichotomous dependent variable: yes/no). This choice was made multiple times (observations nested within subjects), varying both the amount for the immediate reward (independent variable: amount) and the waiting time (independent variable: delay). Subjects might differ in their sensitivity to delays and amounts. To investigate such differences, I attempted to extract BLUPs (or conditional mode) from a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) and correlate these predictions with other measurements. This approach was already followed by [de Water et al. (2017)](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1053811917303038).

**Data structure:**

Each subject has a total of 66 observations. There are 6 observations for each level of variable quantity and 11 for each level of delay.

**GLMM**

I estimated a logistic GLMM using the ´glmer´ from the ´lme4´ package. To obtain the BLUPs for amount and delay, I included a random slope for both variables.
The model was specified as follows:

```
model <- glmer(choice ~ amount + delay + (amount + delay | id), data = allData, 
                family = binomial)
```

The following warning occurred:

```
Warning: Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0396173 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

This warning could be eliminated by increasing the maximum number of iteration by `optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)`.

Output:

[image: Output]

**Problem:**

As can be seen in the output of the model, the random effects of the intercept and amount correlated quite highly, close to the boundary (-.96). However, no singularity warning was issued, nor did `is.singular` indicate a singular fit. If such high correlations accurately reflect the data, the BLUPs might not be useful for further correlation analyses, since they represent almost the same thing.

**Question**: Is this high correlation a problem of the model or does it represent the data correctly? How can I check this?

**Steps I had done so far:**

1. Checking for singularity with `is_singular()`
2. Reduce the complexity of the model (no effect).
3. Residuals diagnostics with `DHARMA` did not indicate any severe violations.
4. Checked for outliers via the `influnce.me` package.
5. Calculate a model with unscaled predictors, since the correlation between intercept and slope should be sensitive to the scaling. However, in this case, the following warning occurred:

```
Warning: Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```